# How do I fetch list of long ids using JpaRepository?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jparepository

I want to fetch List of ids instead of List. How should I define it using JpaRepository syntax? The same code, but I want something like `List<Long> ids...`.

Is there a way to do it using JpaRepository **without** using `@Query`?

```
List<Education> findByUserId(Long userId);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. As a workaround you can use a [Projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/repositories/projections.html) containing only the id.

```
public interface EducationIdProjection {

  Long getId();
}
```

The repository method:

```
List<EducationIdProjection> findByUserId(Long userId);
```

Comment: Well but this is not really a "workaround" is it? As the requirement is to not fetch the whole entity, but a subset (projection) of it, using projections is simply the correct way of doing it.