# JpaRepository: Return a String without using @Query

Tags: java, spring-boot

In a repository I can use the following code to retrieve the name as a string:

```java
@Query("SELECT q.contractorName FROM Quotations q WHERE q.id = :id")
String findContractorNameById(@Param("id") Long id);
```

That works fine, but for such a simple thing, I am just wondering what it needs the `@Query` annotation for. I tried doing the same without it:

```java
String findContractorNameById(Long id);
```

I get the warning:

> 'Quotations' domain type or valid projection interface expected here

Exception:

> org.hibernate.query.QueryTypeMismatchException: Specified result type [java.lang.String] did not match Query selection type - multiple selections: use Tuple or array

Since the ID is unique, I expect a String only, instead of Tuple or Array.

Is that possible without using `@Query`?

Comment: No it is not. Unless you use a projection but that adds an additional wrapper.

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77625807/how-do-i-fetch-list-of-long-ids-using-jparepository).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

You probably have a `Quotation` object like this.

```
@Entity
public class Quotation {

    ...
    private String contractorName;
    ...
}
```

For this, you can create a projection as follows.

```
interface ContractorNameOnly {

    String getContractorName();
}
```

You can implement this in your repository as follows.

```
interface QuotationRepository {

    ContractorNameOnly findContractorNameById(Long id);
}
```

For more, you can check the Spring Projections [page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/repositories/projections.html).